# How can I capture soapui assertions list with status

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertions

If you run a testStep and look at the Assertions.  SoapUI returns the assertion Green/Red as well as adding "- VALID" or "- FAILED"

Question:  Is there a way to captuer that full string?
The name + status

i.e.
SOAP Response - VALID
XPath Match - VALID
Contains - VALID
Not Contains - FAILED

Currently I'm pulling the assertionsList - but I want the extra status piece to go along with it.

Thank you,
Rob

Comment: Yes it's possible to get the name of the assert and append the status to it using groovy script, can you share your actual groovy code to work with it in order to give you a possible answer? `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print all assertions from all the `testSteps` inside a `testCase` you can use the follow groovy script in a `tearDown script` of your `testCase`, it use the [`getAssertionList()`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlTestRequestStep.html#getAssertionList()) which returns a [`TestAssertion`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestAssertion.html) list, and then iterates over it using [`label`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestAssertion.html#getLabel()) and [`status`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestAssertion.html#getStatus()) property:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps.each{ name,props ->
    log.info "Test step name: $name"
    // check that the testStep class support assertions 
    // (for example groovy testStep doesn't)
    if(props.metaClass.respondsTo(props, "getAssertionList")){
        // get assertionList
        props.getAssertionList().each{
           log.info "$it.label - $it.status"
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Not all kind of testStep's have assertions (e.g Groovy script testStep doesn't) so it's necessary to check it before use `getAssertionList()`)

[image]

If you want to get all assertions from one specific `testStep` you can use the same approach in a groovy script:

```
// get the testStep
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('Test Request')

// check that the testStep specific class support assertions 
// (for example groovy testStep doesn't)
if(testStep.metaClass.respondsTo(testStep, "getAssertionList")){
    // print assertion names an its status
    testStep.getAssertionList().each{
       log.info "$it.label - $it.status"    
    }
}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: This does seem to loop through the correct things, however the getAssertionList() part gives me this in the error log: "ERROR:groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.getAssertionList() is applicable for argument types: () values: []"

Comment: @laurencemadill I'll update my response to avoid your problem. The thing is that *Groovy script* test steps (which is implemented using `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestS‌​tep` doesn't have assertions.

Comment: Excellent. I should have spotted that on mine. thank you very much, i've upvoted your answer

Comment: If you want to get rid of the `if` within the loop, you might filter before `each`: `testSteps.findAll { it.respondsTo('getAssertionList') }.each{ name,props -> /* work with assertionList */ }`